# How to store zoom state and update incrementally in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

d3 stores the transform state of an element and updates it when there is a zoom event.

I want to use my own object to store the transform state, and only use the d3 zoom event to update it.

Here's an example of what I've tried to do:

```
// My transform state object
myTransState = {x:0, y:0, k:1}

onZoomEvent(e){

// Update my transform state object with change
myTransState.x += e.transform.x
myTransState.y += e.transform.y
myTransState.k *= e.transform.k

// Reset d3 transform state
e.transform.x = 0
e.transform.y = 0
e.transform.k = 1

}
```

This isn't working. The increment in x and y grows large  and the plot moves far away from the mouse pointer.

I know I can use the d3 state transform directly, however I need to track the state myself for some situations (for example, separate x and y scale factors kx and ky).

Why isn't this working as expected? Is there something else that is modifying the d3 transform state after I reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the event is not enough to reset the zoom transform, because d3 does not store the current zoom coordinates in the event.

To reset the transform, you need to call the [zoom.transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform)

```js
selection.call(zoom.transform, zoomIdentity)
```

Where the `selection` is the same selection that called `selection.call(zoom)`, and `zoomIdentity` is [the identity transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoomIdentity) `{x: 0, y:0, z:1}`

Be aware that calling `zoom.transform` will also trigger the `onZoomEvent` callback. To avoid a infinite loop, you can check if the transform of the event is `{x: 0, y: 0, z: 1}`, and if it is the callback is cancelled.

```js
  onZoomEvent(e){
    if(e.transform.toString() === zoomIdentity.toString()) {
       return
    }


    // Update my transform state object with change
    myTransState.x += e.transform.x
    myTransState.y += e.transform.y
    myTransState.k *= e.transform.k

    // Reset d3 transform state
    selection.call(zoom.transform, zoomIdentity)
}
```

Comment: hmm. I know that d3 stores the current zoom coordinates in the node itself. However, setting the value of `e.transform` does modify it. I confirmed this by setting `e.transform` to `{x:0, y:0, k:1}`. I saw that the selection does in fact get reset back to the start position. However, the zoom event itself doesn't seem to care about the current transform. It doesn't scale and translate relative to the existing transform. I tried your method. It seems to get the job done. Thanks!